# How do I move to the next line in gVim running on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, vim, gvim

Finally decided to take the plunge and start learning vim.

I am however having an issue whereby I can't go the end of the line i.e. after the last letter so that I can hit enter on my keyboard and go to the next line.

I tried using the `l`, `w`, `$`. The only way I have been able to do so is to enter `INSERT` mode and then to use the arrow keys which I would like to avoid. Is there way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In normal mode, use `o` (lowercase o) to "o"pen a new line below the current one and `O` (uppercase O) to open a new line above. *You don't need to be at the end of the line* for these to work which is part of the beauty of Vim.

In insert mode, the `<End>` key works like you'd expect.

If you haven't done it already, Vim comes with the `vimtutor` CLI command. It's a great interactive tutorial that runs in Vim itself that teaches you the basics. It's *highly recommended* to follow it as soon as possible.

Comment: Also, learn the "`a`" and "`A`" commands (`:help a`)

Comment: @romainl - Been learning for a tutorial from Nettuts so hopefully that'll give me a starting platform.

Comment: No, nettuts sucks. Do vimtutor first, as many times as needed to feel comfortable with the basics then watch vimcasts.org from the first to the latest and **DON'T INSTALL ANY PLUGIN/CONFIG PACKAGE LIKE JANUS OR SPF13.**